# Python Asyncio - Eventloop in a contextmanager

Tags: python, python-asyncio, event-loop, contextmanager

Since I dont like the approach to use `loop.run()` for various reasons I wanted to code contextual loop, since the docs states on different occasions that if you don't go with the canonical `.run()` you have to prevent memory leaks by yourself ([i.e](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.shutdown_asyncgens)). After a bit of research it seems like the python devs answer this feature with *We don't need it!*. While contextmanagers seems in general perfectly fine if you using the lower level api of asyncio, see [PEP 343 - The “with” Statement](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/#examples) exampel 10:

> This can be used to deterministically close anything with a close
> method, be it file, generator, or something else. It can even be used
> when the object isn’t guaranteed to require closing (e.g., a function
> that accepts an arbitrary iterable)

***So can we do it anyway?***

Related links:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue24795
- https://bugs.python.org/issue32875
- https://groups.google.com/g/python-tulip/c/8bRLexUzeU4
- https://bugs.python.org/issue19860#msg205062
- https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/261

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can have a context manager for our event loop, even if there seems no good practice via subclassing due the c implementations [(i.e)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8c349565e8a442e17f1a954d1a9996847749d778/Lib/asyncio/events.py#L741). Basically the idea crafted out below is the following:

### TL;DR

1. Create an Object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` to have the syntax `with` working.
2. Instead of usually returning the object, we return the loop that is served by asyncio
3. wrapping the `asycio.loop.close()` so that the loop gets stopped and our `__exit__` method gets invoked before.
4. Close all connections which can lead to memory leaks and then close the loop.

**Side-note**

The implementation is due a wrapper object that returns a **new** loop into an annonymous block statement. Be aware that `loop.stop()` [will finalize the loop and no further actions should be called](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.close). Overall the code below is just a little help and more a styling choice in my opinion, especially due the fact that it is no real subclass. But I think if someone wants to use the lower api without minding to finalize everything before, here is a possibility.

```
import asyncio

class OpenLoop:

    def close(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self._loop.stop()

    def _close_wrapper(self):
        self._close = self._loop.close
        self._loop.close = self.close

    def __enter__(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self._close_wrapper()
        return self._loop
    
    def __exit__(self,*exc_info):
        asyncio.run(self._loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        asyncio.run(self._loop.shutdown_default_executor())
        #close other services
        self._close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with OpenLoop() as loop:
        loop.call_later(1,loop.close)
        loop.run_forever()
    assert loop.is_closed()
```